# Deduction of a lower bound

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a>0$, $b>0$ two positive constants  and $f≥0$ , for all $x∈I⊂ℝ$, 
I have:

$a≤f(x)g(x)$ and     $b≤g(x)$.

How to justify that
    $(a/b)≤f(x)$, for all $x∈I$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false, you can let $f(x)$ be any positive constant function and compensate by making $g$ very large. There is nothing saying that $g$ can't be as large as we want.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true,

Consider $a=1, b=1, I=[1,2]$ and the functions over $I$:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=x$

You have $1\leq f(x).g(x)$ and $1\leq g(x)$ but $\frac{a}{b}=1\leq f(x)$ only for $x=1$.

Comment: Are they additional conditions to justify my deduction?

Comment: I think it is clear that this implies that f>0 for all x in I,
How to justify the existence of a positive constant c>0 such that f>c,  and the relation between  a and c?